# Reversi like game detect color diagonally

Tags: c#, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I am recreating the classic Reversi game but I am having trouble on trying to correctly change colors diagonally. I have two for loops but they are not working correctly can anyone have a look at my code and tell me what I am doing wrong.

(please look at my for loop)

This image illustrates what my problems is:

[image]

This is my code:

```
        private void ClickedButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button s = (Button)sender;
            int x = int.Parse(s.Name.Split()[0]);
            int y = int.Parse(s.Name.Split()[1]);

            if (cnt == 0)
            {
                cnt = 1;
                s.BackColor = Color.Black;

                for (int i = 3; i > x; --i)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < y; ++j)
                    {
                        if (b[i, j].BackColor == Color.Black)
                        {
                            b[i - 1, j + 1].BackColor = Color.Black;

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                cnt = 0;
                s.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }

           // MessageBox.Show("you have clicked button: " + x +" "+ y);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't look like Reversi to me.  Where are the white tiles?

Comment: Really?! That cos its not complete yet that's not the point at this stage.. first I need to correctly detect a color diagonally then develop it further. sorry if this does not satisfy your eye

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code in the debugger?

Comment: I have but I cannot understand why it does that

Comment: You can't always start at the edge of the board and work your way in.  If your rule is that only the tiles adjacent to the clicked tile should be turned black, then only loop through those tiles.

Comment: you are right @mbeckish i am trying to implement that solution but if you have something for me please feel free to post

Comment: Put a break point above the loop and step through the code

Comment: Still cant solve it I'm just mentally wrestling with it @AustinHenley

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    private void ClickedButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button s = (Button)sender;
        int x = int.Parse(s.Name.Split()[0]);
        int y = int.Parse(s.Name.Split()[1]);

        if (b[x, y].BackColor == Color.Red || b[x, y].BackColor == Color.Black)
          return;

        var color = cnt == 1 ? Color.Red : Color.Black;
        cnt = 1 - cnt;
        b[x, y].BackColor = color;

          int len = 4;

          var directions = new[]
          {
            new {x =  0, y =  1}, 
            new {x =  0, y = -1}, 
            new {x =  1, y =  0},
            new {x = -1, y =  0}, 
            new {x = -1, y = -1},
            new {x =  1, y = -1},
            new {x = -1, y =  1},
            new {x =  1, y =  1}
          };
          b[x, y].BackColor = color;

          foreach (var dir in directions)
          {
            for (var i = 1; i < len; ++i)
            {
              var xi = x + i * dir.x;
              var yi = y + i * dir.y;
              if (xi < 0 || xi >= len || yi < 0 || yi >= len)
                break;
              if (b[xi, yi].BackColor != Color.Black && b[xi, yi].BackColor != Color.Red)
                break;
              if (b[xi, yi].BackColor == color)
              {
                for (var j = 1; j < i; ++j)
                  b[x + j * dir.x, y + j * dir.y].BackColor = color;
                break;
              }
            }
          }
    }
```

Comment: Hmm i used the whole thing doesn't really do anything.. (I'm close to solving it another way but thanks for but effort)

Comment: wow its really good thanks @DarkGray

Answer (score 0):

Answer

```
private void ClickedButton(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button s = (Button)sender;
            int x = int.Parse(s.Name.Split()[0]);
            int y = int.Parse(s.Name.Split()[1]);

           // if (b[x, y].BackColor != Color.Red && b[x, y].BackColor != Color.Black)
            //    return;

            var color = cnt == 1 ? Color.Red : Color.Black;
            cnt = 1 - cnt;
            b[x, y].BackColor = color;

            int len = 4;

            var directions = new[]
          {
            new {x =  0, y =  1}, 
            new {x =  0, y = -1}, 
            new {x =  1, y =  0},
            new {x = -1, y =  0}, 
            new {x = -1, y = -1},
            new {x =  1, y = -1},
            new {x = -1, y =  1},
            new {x =  1, y =  1}
          };
            b[x, y].BackColor = color;

            foreach (var dir in directions)
            {
                for (var i = 1; i < len; ++i)
                {
                    var xi = x + i * dir.x;
                    var yi = y + i * dir.y;
                    if (xi < 0 || xi >= len || yi < 0 || yi >= len)
                        break;
                    if (b[xi, yi].BackColor != Color.Black && b[xi, yi].BackColor != Color.Red)
                        break;
                    if (b[xi, yi].BackColor == color)
                    {
                        for (var j = 1; j < i; ++j)
                            b[x + j * dir.x, y + j * dir.y].BackColor = color;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```